# Motorola Z Play having unusable screen

Tags: touchscreen, broken-screen, motorola

I dropped by Moto Z play a few days ago, and when i dropped it, the touchscreen just stopped. I can see everything that is happening on the screen, like the time, notifications and other things on the lock screen, but the touchscreen, as well as the fingerprint reader, is dead. I have tried accessing my data in multiple ways, but nothing has worked.
If anyone can help, please i would appreciate it.

Thanks in advance, and regards.

Comment: If only the touch digitizer is not working you can attach mouse and/or keyboard via USB OTG cable. See also https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/broken-screen/info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that if i get a dongle, and attach the dongle to the USB-C, and attach a mouse to that dongle, then i can operate the phone a bit hard, but it works!!